# What is the verb that means to capitalize the first letter of a word?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, capitalization

The word I'm looking for means to capitalize the first letter of some words, but I want to use a single verb since I need to say this many times, as in "*** all the words that appear in the table headers".

Is there such a verb?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you speak of capitalizing a word, that normally means to capitalize only the first letter.  If you were to say "capitalize all the words that appear in the table headers", I believe this would get your meaning across fine (and as always in specifications, a little example goes a *very* long way).

The only other likely interpretation, putting it in all caps, is not normally expressed that way; usually one would have to say "put the words that appear in the table headers in all caps" to communicate that.

Comment: "Put in all caps" or "uppercase", even.

Comment: For all-caps, I'd say something like "Use uppercase [letters] for table headers".

Answer (score 12):

In the programming community, this activity (capitalizing the first letter of every word) is known as "Propercasing" ...

> UPPERCASE
>
> lowercase
>
> Propercase
>
> CamelCase
>
> Title Case (Some Short Words Don't Qualify for Capitalization)

The name "Proper Case" comes from the capitalization rules for proper nouns.  See [Wikipedia's article on Sentence Case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_case).

Comment: I love that "the programming community" is constituted such that I've been programming for the last 27 years and this is the first time I've encountered this term.

Comment: (*sigh*; ninja'd) Never come across the term "propercase" before... do you know which programming language or library it originated in, and how widely it's used?

Comment: I don't really know, except to say that it's been in VB since VB4 and that Google search results for "proper case" have info ranging from 1998 to 2011.

Comment: Ok. My own googling suggested that it might be a VB thing. Looks like with the .NET framework MS switched to using the term TitleCase (c.f. `TextInfo.ToTitleCase`)

Comment: Proper Casing Is Not "In Programming Community", It's Just a VB Thing. It differ from Title Case that latter doesn't capitalize articles, pronouns and some conjutives.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with chaos, but you could also say "put the table headers in title case".

Unfortunately that doesn't completely remove the ambiguity, since [styles vary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Headings_and_publication_titles) on whether prepositions, conjunctions and so on should be capitalised. The page linked also mentions *start case* as having the first letter of every word capitalized, but I must admit I've never seen that term (start case) used before.

Answer (score 0):

Besides capitalize, my first instinct on the matter, "put into uppercase" could be another option.